# setInterval function in vue mounted() not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

My function works fine but setInterval not working, I want my `h1`'s `text-shadow` to be randomized(already wrote that function) and changed every 1000ms with the `setInterval()` but it doesn't seem to work

Here's code:

```js
  data(){
      return {
        textshadow: '1.3px 2px 0',
        textshadowColor: '#333'
      }
  },
  methods:{
    playy:function(){
      var test = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
      this.textshadowColor = test;
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    setInterval(this.playy(),1000);
  }
```

```html
  <div class="main">
      <h1 v-bind:style="{textShadow : '1.3px 2px 0' + textshadowColor}">{{ title }}</h1>
  </div>
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:22px;
  color:#fff;
  text-shadow:1.3px 2px 0;
  cursor: nesw-resize;
  transition: .2s;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `mounted()` is being called?

Comment: @JDunken I don't understand your question

Comment: If `mounted()` is never invoked the interval will never start. I'm now guessing it's a function that vue calls itself. Have you put a `console.log` in there to be sure? Oh and what @Deykun said in their answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try passing `this.playy` instead of `this.playy()` setInterval expects the reference of the function.

`setInterval(this.playy,1000);`

Comment: This is correct. If you pass `this.playy()`, you're passing the value that's been _returned_ by the `playy` function, which in this case is `undefined`. That means, `setInterval` will attempt to invoke `undefined` rather than your function. By passing `this.playy` (no invocation), you're passing a reference to the function itself.